# NodeJs pipe readable stream to writeable stream creates corrupted file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io, express, request

I have created a simple express app(for testing purposes) that sends file.
I am trying to use the request module to get that file back while using the pipe function.
below is a sample of my server.js and client.js

The following is server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/file', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile('/Users/fouad/Desktop/helloman.amr', function (err) {
    if (err)
        throw new Error(err);
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The following is client.js

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

request({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/file',
    method: 'POST',
    encoding: null
}, function (err, data, response) {
    if (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
    data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/Users/user/Desktop/hellomanoutput1.amr'));

    // this works perfectly while piping does not work
    //var b = new Buffer(response)
    //fs.writeFile('/Users/user/Desktop/hellomanoutput.amr', b, function     (err) {
    //    if (err)
    //        throw new Error(err);
    //})
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `response.pipe`?

Comment: @BenFortune no, i just tried it and same result, the response is a buffer while data is an IncomingMessage which has the pipe function

Comment: did u try just `request.post('http://localhost:3000/file').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/Users/user/Desktop/hellomanoutput1.amr'))` ?

Comment: @JakubMartyčák That works, Thanks a lot but why can't I do the same from within the callback using the data object?

Comment: Its because `data`  is not readable stream, you can see it if u log `data.readable`

Comment: @JakubMartyčák Thanks a lot, I thought that because data is of type IncomingMessage and the node docs says that IncomingMessage is a readable stream and because data had a pipe function then piping would work, i guess i was wrong

Comment: You're welcome... the `data` param actually is full response object, so thats probably, why the `pipe` method is present and last param - `response` is just response body